# What should be my connection URL for my database on localhost and website developed using Java working online?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, heroku, localhost

I have my website https://www.riyajobcard.herokuapp.com working on an online server. I want this website to be online and its database to be working on localhost of my computer. Is this possible?

My connectionDB.java file's code look like this:

```
package modal;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionDb {

         public static Connection getConnection(){  
                Connection con=null;  
                try{  
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                    con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jcps","root","");                
                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
                return con; 
         }  
}
```

I expect that the connection of a live website to a local database should be done successfully.

Comment: `localhost` is not known to remote computers and will only work if your website is on your own (local) computer. To provide access from a remote computer to your local database you need to grant the database user (`root`) remote access, use your (current and probably changing) public IP address instead of `localhost`, open in your firewall port 3306 and map requests to this port in your router to your local computer

Answer (score 0):

When you define a connection with `localhost` for an app, it would resolve to the server on which the app is hosted. It is not advised to run an app on a different server with the database on your local computer, since it would lose the connection when your computer is either shutdown or goes offline.

But even if you must do it, you would need to provide the IP of your computer, and allow access via the firewall with the necessary port open for the app running on a different server to access your database. So essentially, you should replace `localhost` with the **public IP address of your computer** on which the database is running.

Comment: @jashpatel did this help answer your query?